# Magento 2 - Generate css dynamically

Tags: magento2, module, css, dynamic

I have an observer and i need to generate a css file dynamically - using my admin theme setting configuration - calling my observer function.

Comment: In one of my custom module from backend, i can change the colors and those color values are used in phtml file and finally that css with updated value is called in footer or header where you want, do you want the same or something more dynamic ?

Comment: yes the same thing for a custom theme. i have just create admin config and controller on admin setting save

Comment: so where you stuck ?

Comment: i need to create the function to generate css in my custom theme from phtml. i don't kwon how to get code from phtml in controller function and generate variable path to my custom theme css folder where i have to put css generated

Comment: if i understood, you just want to update the css values right which are changed form module setting page ?

Comment: yes it is right

Comment: wait i am sharing some code , may be it help you a bit

Comment: have a look to my answer, i didn`t found any other method when i am trying to do the same , if you found any issues plz feel free to share and to  update the approach.

Comment: i'm try another approach, please see my question update

Comment: As in my case I just need to update few tags only I tried as below , that's working as well. I didn't tried as you are trying, but surely try to do that once I got time .if found any solution , update here to so that it help others as well.

Comment: Are you able to do in the way you are trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As per your initial question:

**Step 1 .**

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/Block/dynamiccss.php`

In this file we get the css values

like below :

```
 public function color_right_headingh() {
        return $this->_helper->color_right_headingh();
 }
```

**Step 2:**
In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/Helper/Data.php`

`We must create the helper methods attached to this view`

```
public function color_right_headingh() {
        return $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(self::COLORRIGHTHEADING);
}
```

**Step 3:**
In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/HestabitCompanyname/Modulename/view/frontend/templates/dynamiccss.phtml`

```
 .someClassTag {
    color :<?php echo $color_right_headingh; ?>;
 }
```

**Step 4:** : YOu can choose the pages on which you want to change the values or use `default.xml` for gloabl scope of your phtml file.

In `/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/Companyname/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/cms_index_index.xml`

```
   <body>
           <!-- //sidebar.additional  on home page
                name ="page.bottom" at bottom of home page

                name= "footer" before="-" :: above footer
                name="footer" after="-"   :: below footer
            -->
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
                    <block class="Companyname\ModuleName\Block\Dynamiccss" name="dynamiccss" template="Companyname_ModuleName::dynamiccss.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my configuration Helper

```
namespace Altravista\ThemeSetting\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class ConfigSetting extends AbstractHelper
{

    const XML_PATH_THEMESETTING = 'themesetting/';

    public function getConfigValue($field, $storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            $field, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId
        );
    }

    public function getGeneralConfig($code, $storeId = null)
    {

        return $this->getConfigValue(self::XML_PATH_THEMESETTING .'general/'. $code, $storeId);
    }

}
```

This is my GenerateCss Helper

```
namespace Altravista\ThemeSetting\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use \Altravista\ThemeSetting\Helper\ConfigSetting;

class GenerateStyle extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $helperConfigSetting;

    public function __construct(
        ConfigSetting $helperConfigSetting
    ) {
        $this->helperConfigSetting = $helperConfigSetting; 
    }

    public function ciao(){
        return 'Hallo :)';
    }

    public function getConf($data){
        return $this->helperConfigSetting->getGeneralConfig($data);
    }

    public function override_css() {
        $line = "\n";
        $style = 'a { color:'.$this->getConf('link_color').'}'.$line;
        $style .= 'a:hover { color:'.$this->getConf('link_hover_color').'}'.$line;
        return $style;
     }

    public function generateStoreCss() {

        $content = $this->override_css();
        $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/app/design/frontend/Altravista/bookshop/web/css/design.css","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$content);
        fclose($fp);
    }

}
```

this is my observer

```
namespace Altravista\ThemeSetting\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
use Altravista\ThemeSetting\Helper\GenerateStyle;

class ConfigObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @param Logger $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        Logger $logger,
        GenerateStyle $helperGenerateStyle
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->helperGenerateStyle = $helperGenerateStyle;
    }

    public function execute(EventObserver $observer)
    {
        $message =  $this->helperGenerateStyle->ciao();
        $this->logger->info($message);
        $this->logger->debug($message);
        $this->helperGenerateStyle->generateStoreCss();
        //$this->logger->info($observer->getStore());
    }
}
```